# QGlWidget does not properly update if Windows compositor switched off

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

Noticed that the update of my scene which is embedded into a QGlWidget does not work properly if I switch of the transparency in Windows 7. The scene is not updated completely or just after a while. The events are properly called. The OpenGL context uses 3.3. Looks like a frame buffer problem. Someone ever noticed similar behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a known problem with the compositor, I have to call InvalidateRect.

```
InvalidateRect((HWND)winId(), NULL, TRUE);
```